# how to convert Ge'ez -1 font to unicode (power geez unicode )

Tags: unicode

i was trying to publish an article which is written in Gee'ez -1 font Microsoft word. but i copy and past the article to a web it converted some ting unknown characters. i try to change the font which is supported by the web browse like Nyala,power Ge'ez Unicode and other but it don't work too. so i need to convert all the characters in to power Ge'ez Unicode.

This is what gonna happen when i copy paste to the web page

SÓu=Á   እ— ¾c¨< MÐ‹ u}KÃU ¡`e+Á•‹ G<L‹” እÓ²=›wN?` እ”ÇK እ“U“K”:: ›UL"‹” እÓ²=›wN?`እ”ÅJ’ uTS“‹” ¾}’X ¨Å እ`c< çKAƒ እ“Å`dK”:: /uçKAƒ እ“’ÒÓ[ªK”/ ‹Ó` c=Å`ew” ‹Ó^‹”” እ”Ç=ðታM” እ”ÖÃkªK”:: uHÃT•ƒ እÓ²=›wN?` ›ÖÑv‹” እ”ÇK እ”[ÇK”:: pÆe ä¨Áe[ÓØ ¾T“¾¨<”U ’Ñ`¾T>Áe[Ç ’¨<$:: እ”ÇK (°w ) ›UL"‹” እÓ²=›wN?`” u¯Ã’ YÒ‹” v“¾¨

TS” ŸT¨p  ÃkÉTM c¨< ›ekÉV ›U• kØKA u=Á¨  SJ’<” ÑMëM“M:: pÆe â?Øae #እ—e ›”} ¡`e„e ¾QÁ¨< ¾እÓ²=›wN?` MÏ እ”ÅJ”I ›U’“M ›¨kÉU c=Áe [Ç u}ÚT]U pÆe ä¨” MÏ uTS”“ uT¨p$ c=M u(›?ô ) }“ÓbM::  vÁU” •a uእc< Sê“ƒ vM‰K ’u`:: እÓ²=›wN?`” T¨p c=vM vQ]¨<”' ðnÆ” Ÿእ— ¾T>Öuk¨<” ¾õÖ<`’ƒ É`h እ—U Ÿእ`c< ¾U”h¨<” T¨p ’¨<:: እÓ²=›wN?`” uYÒ© U`U` T¨p ›Ã‰MU“:: uእ`c< ›U• uእ`c< uSê“ƒ °¨SêNõƒ” SSS` T¨pU ŸeI}ƒ ÁÉ“M::

ÃI” እ”Ç=I Ÿ}[Ç” እÓ²=›wN?`T’¨<; Y^¨<e U”É” ’¨<; vI`Ã¨K¨<” ØÁo M”SMe እ”‹LK”:: eK²=IU u²=I ¾GM­} እÓ²=›wN?`ƒUI`ታ‹”:-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i got the answer**

just download Abnet Amharic virtual key board you can download from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HacFZdtGP4gS6sd5oocT9oaHtKrgxNkb)
and install it to your computer and Abnet have default character converters 
see the steps below

1. 1 install Abnet and open it
2. 2 in the try icon of Abnet right click and select converter [enter
   image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeEtc.jpg)
3. small converter window will appear click on the Microsoft word
   document icon and select the document that you went to convert(for
   better result the document that you went to convert should be in
   .doc extension in my case .docx also works fine ) and the word
   document that you went to convert have to be in its original written
   font in my case Ge'ez-1 .

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzcQo.png)
4. click on the convert button  and the original word document will
   open automatically and the converter will read each character and
   converted to the selected font type .wait until it finish reading
   all the characters in the document . after it finished it will close
   the document.

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V5Xs.png)
5. after converting finish the converter will save you a new converted
   document in the same directory which the original file is located
   win the name suffixed  by "[original document name ]converted.doc"

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ999.png)
6. then you all done with converting